# CSS - Absolute positioned element at the end of parent without knowing it's height?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Let's say we have such html

```
<div class="at-end-holder">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="at-end">
</div>
```

And we want **top edge of image to stick with bottom edge of it's parent.**

**If** we'd know image height (let's say its 150px), then we can just set `bottom: -150px`. But what if we dont know it's height?

I **don't** want to use **js**. I mean - **I don't.**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z74bqj6m/1/) is some playground. Bottom case looks exatcly as needed, but I assumed there I know image height.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Of course you can use `top:100%`, as Josh suggested – but would you then not have problems with the _next_ piece of content that follows after that? The image will either overlap it, or get hidden under it …

Comment: @CBroe Yes and that is exactly what I need. I have some kind of curves at top/bottom of many elements that overlay each other and I wanted to avoid writing css with height of each of them.

Comment: OK, fair enough :) Just wanted to make sure that you don’t get any _unwanted_ side effects here …

Answer (score 8):

Since the element is absolutely positioned *relative* to the parent, you could simply use `top: 100%` to position it at the bottom edge of the parent.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/nd0v80bu/)

```
.at-end-holder.example .at-end {
    top: 100%;
}
```

```css
.at-end-holder {
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}
.at-end-holder .at-end {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="at-end-holder">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis vero veritatis, assumenda reiciendis vel voluptate, rem eaque, ut quisquam qui sit molestias omnis. Officia, illum repellat quasi eius, magni soluta?
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="at-end">
</div>

<div class="at-end-holder example">
  <h1>THIS I NEED, BUT I DONT KNOW IMAGE HEIGHT</h1>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis vero veritatis, assumenda reiciendis vel voluptate, rem eaque, ut quisquam qui sit molestias omnis. Officia, illum repellat quasi eiusmagni soluta?
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="at-end">
</div>
```